# keyboardWillShowNotification fired when I press return key (only first time I press it)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have very strange issue which happens when I hit return key, and it happens only when I hit it first time, every next time it works as expected.

I have simple class to manage keyboard, it accepts array of text fields which I resisted to delegate to my class, also I register keyboard notifications:

```
    public init(withTextFields textFields: [UITextField]) {
        super.init()

        guard textFields.count > 0 else { return }
        textFields.forEach{ $0.delegate = self }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }
```

Those are my methods which simple prints out text for debuting purposes:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("aaaa")
}
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    print("bbbb")
}
```

and my UITextFieldDelegate:

```
    public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("111")
    }

    public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print("222")
    }

    public func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        print("333")
        return true
    }
```

In my view controller I have two text fields which I pass to my class.
When I tap on the first one I can see:

```
111
aaa
```

which is what I expecting. the problem show up when I press return key on my keyboard, then it logs:

```
aaa
333
```

but it logs it only first time I press it, every other time it logs:
`333`.

When I press return key the keyboard's already shown on the screen so why it calls `UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification` again? My textFieldShouldReturn it's empty.

Comment: Are you trying to make UI change according to what the keyboard covers? If so I would suggest using keyboardFrameChange rather than show/hide

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `resignFirstResponder()` and/or `view.endEditing(true)` in `textFieldShouldReturn`.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Also try to change `UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification` to `UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification`

Comment: It's not my intention to call resignFirstResponder() but it still logs (when I press text field: 111 aaa and after I press return: aaaa 333 bbbb 222). The delegates are set correctly because they print out text to console. Thanks.

Comment: Try to change `UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification` to `UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification`

Comment: Can you explain what you expect?

Comment: What you explained is works as expected in swift. If you want to switch between textfields, you need to change responder: `firstTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` or `secondTextField.becomeFirstResponder()`

Comment: It calls keyboardWillShow whey you press on the text field and it calls it again when you press return key. I'm expecting it to call keyboardWillShow when you press the text field and textFieldShouldReturn when you press the return key.

Comment: Hm... Do you unsubscribe this notifications on `viewWillDisapear`?